# Save model after each epoch - AllenNLP

Tags: allennlp

Is there a parameter that I can set in the config file (maybe for the trainer?) that would save the model (archive) after each epoch or after a specific number of steps?
I'm using seq2seq dataloader and "composed_seq2seq" as my model. This is how my trainer looks like currently:

```
"trainer": {
"num_epochs": 50,
"cuda_device": 0,
"optimizer": {
  "type": "adamw",
  "lr": 0.0005
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do with a model from every epoch/some number of steps? I think it already archives the model every time it gets a new best score, so I'm wondering what you want to do that can't be accomplished with that.

Edit:

It looks like AllenNLP already saves a model every epoch, but it only keeps a maximum of 2 by default. I believe you can change that by adding a `checkpointer` to your training config, e.g.:

```
  "trainer": {
    "checkpointer": {
      "num_serialized_models_to_keep": num_epochs
    },
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @JacobMorrison! My evaluation process is a bit complicated, so I do it separately myself. I want to be able to load the models later and run them on the dev set to find the best one and also run some analysis on the different outputs I get on dev.

Comment: Gotcha! I looked into it some more and updated my answer with more details.